# How to subtract Geometry Point Polygons in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, polygon

I have two json arrays, one for background polygon and one for other polygon.
And from them, I got two polygon layers.

```js
backgroundLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Background Layer", {styleMap: backgroundStyleMap} );
....
totalAreaPolygon = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]))
backgroundLayer.addFeatures([totalAreaPolygon])
```

And same for other polygon.

How can I subtract the other polygon from background polygon as shown in the picture (right polygon).

[image]

This is one of the examples from OpenLayers.
http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/donut.html

Comment: Where'd the 'geodesic' in your title come from? And is your end goal to create a donut polygon?

Comment: Oh... Yes, I want to create a donut polygon by subtracting smallLayer from backgroundLayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new Polygon with 2 components or `addComponent` to the existing polygon.

Notice what the polygon constructor says in the [documentation](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.7/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry/Polygon-js.html).

> The first ring
>   (this.component[0])is the outer bounds of the polygon and all
>   subsequent rings (this.component[1-n]) are internal holes.

Basically the first component (LinearRing) in the polygon is the perimeter and the 2nd is the donut hole.

And this is exactly how the [Polygon Handler (OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon)](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/browser/trunk/openlayers/lib/OpenLayers/Handler/Polygon.js) does it in the [openlayers example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/donut.html) you posted.

Here's a function that will return a new feature polygon from two other features:

```js
function Subtract(bigFeature, smallFeature) {

    var newPolygon = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon(bigFeature.geometry.components);
    var newFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(newPolygon);
    //Add Inner DONUT HOLE!
    newPolygon.addComponent(smallFeature.geometry.components[0]);

    return newFeature;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

[Here's a DEMO of the usage.](http://jsfiddle.net/6bPBc/1/)

```js
var newFeature = Subtract(layerBig.features[0], layerSmall.features[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)? Is a port of the popular Java Topology Suite to JavaScript to perform graphic operations like the difference you are asking for but I haven't used it and it's pretty new so no idea from first hand.

Here's an example of using the `difference` function:

```
function subtractFromFeature(positiveFeature, negativeFeature) {
    var parser = new jsts.io.OpenLayersParser();
    return new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        parser.write(
            parser.read(positiveFeature.geometry).difference(
                parser.read(negativeFeature.geometry)
            )
        )
    );
}

// Where `bigFeature` and `littleFeature` are instances of OpenLayers.Feature.Vector
var differenceFeature = subtractFromFeature(bigFeature, littleFeature);
```

Comment: Example in action: http://jsfiddle.net/colllin/pRSt7/

Comment: works like a dream.